# How to Play online audio streaming in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am developing one application where i want to play live audio radio. I have an url using which i will stream the audio. I have two urls,

```
http://54.36.166.45:9308/;__idm_id__=1010706433
http://54.36.166.45:9306/;__idm_id__=1010706433
```

The first one work properly, but the second one doesn't work, though both of these urls works fine in browser.

Here is my code:

```
public class ZTest1  extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btn;
private boolean playPause;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private boolean initialStage = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ztest1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.audioStreamBtn);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!playPause) {
                btn.setText("Pause Streaming");
                if (initialStage) {
                    new Player().execute("http://54.36.166.45:9306/;__idm_id__=1010706433");
                } else {
                    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                }
                playPause = true;
            } else {
                btn.setText("Launch Streaming");
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }
                playPause = false;
            }
        }
    });
}

class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Boolean prepared = false;
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    initialStage = true;
                    playPause = false;
                    btn.setText("Launch Streaming");
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyAudioStreamingApp", e.getMessage());
            prepared = false;
        }
        return prepared;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
        initialStage = false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
}
```

I added both "RECORD_AUDIO" and "MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" permissions.

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use audioPlayer in a Dilaog

class AudioPlayerDialog(context: Context, audioLink: String) : Dialog(context) {

```
private var mContext = context
private var play = false
private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
private var total: Int = 0
var view: View? = null
private val link = audioLink

init {

    setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(
            ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    val params = AbsListView.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    val inflater = this.layoutInflater;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_dialog, null)
    params.width = 700
    params.height = 680
    window.attributes.windowAnimations = R.style.PauseDialogAnimation;
    setContentView(view, params)
    view!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    try {
        init()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    initContent()
    StaticDataClassJava.scaleViewAndChildren(view!!, StaticDataClassJava.scaleFactor)

}


private fun initContent() {

    playBtn!!.setOnClickListener {
        if (!play) {

            playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            play()

        } else {

            playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            mediaStop()
        }
    }
    leaveBtn.setOnClickListener {
        mediaStop()
        dismiss()
    }
}


@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun init() {

    try {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        val streamPath = link//enter path
        mediaPlayer!!.setDataSource(streamPath)
        mediaPlayer!!.prepare()
        total = mediaPlayer!!.duration
        musicSeekBar.max = total
        play()
        getSeekBarStatus()
    } catch (ex: MalformedURLException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Wrong url for mediaplayer! $ex")
    } catch (ex: IllegalStateException) {
    } catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Wrong url for mediaplayer! $ex")
    }
}

private fun play() {
    mediaPlayer!!.start()
    play = true
}

private fun mediaStop() {
    mediaPlayer!!.pause()
    play = false

}


private fun getSeekBarStatus() {

    Thread(Runnable {
        var currentPosition = 0

        while (mediaPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000)
                currentPosition = mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            musicSeekBar!!.progress = currentPosition
        }
    }).start()

    musicSeekBar!!.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : 
  SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        internal var progress = 0

        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, ProgressValue: Int, 
       fromUser: Boolean) {
            if (fromUser) {
                mediaPlayer!!.seekTo(ProgressValue)//if user drags the seekbar, it 
             gets the position and updates in textView.
            }
            val mMinutes = (ProgressValue / 1000 / 60).toLong()//converting into 
            minutes
            val mSeconds = ProgressValue / 1000 % 60//converting into seconds
            // SongProgress.setText(mMinutes + ":" + mSeconds);
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {

        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {

        }
    })
  }


      }
```

and this when i call the dialog

```
     val dialog = AudioPlayerDialog(this@OrderDetailScreenActivity, audioLink)
                dialog.show()
```